# Composite 2 video(.mov) files using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, composite

Novice user of ffmpeg but going thru whatever docs I can find online.

For a current project I will need to composite 2 videos together to create a .flv file.

Does anyone know the commands to do this?

Comment: Do you mean something like chroma key compositing? I'm not totally sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: One video is smaller and would be 'framed' by the larger video

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
ffmpeg -i background_file.l -i file_to_overlay.flv -filter_complex overlay=0:0 -acodec aac -strict -2 out.flv
```

See http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#overlay-1 for more details.
Also you can add the scaler in the filter chain and scale things appropriately too.

Do a ffmpeg -filters to see the filters available.